# Binary addition in c with character arrays

Tags: c, for-loop, char, function-definition

I am trying to add two binary numbers in a c function, and I can't get the result I'm looking for.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * sadd(char bn1[], char bn2[], char s[]){ //Function to add the binary numbers

        int i;
        int co = 0;
        int num = 0;

        for(i = 15; i>0; i++){
                num = (int)bn1[i] + (int)bn2[i] + co;
                co = 0;
                if(num == 2){
                        co = 1;
                        s[i] = '0';
                }
                else{
                        s[i] = (char)num;
                }
        }
        return s;
}
```

Comment: First of all, `'1' != 1` (and the same for all digits).

Comment: where did 15 come from?

Comment: The base specifies how we *write* a number, not usually the operations that can be performed on that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop

```
for(i = 15; i>0; i++){
```

is incorrect. Instead of decreasing the variable i it is increased. It seems you mean

```
for(i = 15; i>=0; i--){
```

This statement

```
num = (int)bn1[i] + (int)bn2[i] + co;
```

should be rewritten like

```
num = bn1[i] - '0' + bn2[i] - '0' + co;
```

And this statement

```
s[i] = (char)num;
```

should be rewritten like

```
s[i] = num + '0';
```

And you are not processing the case when  num is equal tp 3 when co is equal to 1 and bn[i] and bn2[i] are both equal to '1'.

Instead of this if statement

```
co = 0;
if(num == 2){
        co = 1;
        s[i] = '0';
}
else{
        s[i] = (char)num;
}
```

you could just write

```
s[i] = num % 2 + '0';
cp = num / 2;
```

Comment: also OP doesnt deal with the case of '1' + '1' + (carry = '1')

Comment: So, I think your answer should be the accepted one, sorry for stealing your thunder here. I +1'ed you though.

Answer (score 0):

@VladFromMoscow has provided a patient and valid answer. But - you could have figured this out on your own, if you were to step through a run of your program, using a debugger.

Here are two Stackoverflow questions about debugging on Linux and on Windows:

- [How to debug a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590931/1593077)
- [How do you debug a C program on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176795/1593077)

If you were to debug the program, stepping through individual commands, you would notice that:

- The loop runs for more than 15 iterations, with `j` increasing.
- The value of num is rarely between `0` and `3`.

and then you could have thought about *why* that happens, and reached the same conclusion as in Vlad's answer.

Also, and for future reference - most StackOverflow users expect question askers to perform their "due diligence", making reasonable efforts to figure out their problems before asking us for a solution. Now that you know about debuggers - please use one before asking "Why does my program not do what I expected".