# Reverse strings of vowels

Tags: c

I have to find the vowels in an input string and return the string of the vowels in reverse order.

Example input: "woUIW"

The expected output is "IUOo"

But I cannot use pointers, only recursion.

This is my attempt:

```
void letters_revers(char s[])
{
    int i = 0,g,len,right,left;
    char reversed[10];
    len=strlen(reversed)-1; // get the length of the string
    left = 0; // set left index at 0
    right = len - 1; // set right index len - 1
    while(i!='\0')
    {

        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] =='o' || s[i]=='O' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] == 'U')
        { reversed[i]+=s[i];
            for(g = len - 1; g >= 0; g--)
            {
                printf("%c", reversed[g]);
            }
        }

    }i++;
}
```

Comment: Your outer loop condition is immediately false. Why would you take the length of an empty string, and why subtract 1 from it? Why a loop within a loop? Please show what you have done to debug this situation.

Comment: i have inserted the vowels to a new array then i want to print it in a revers way

Comment: No, you have not inserted the vowels to a new array. Did you run your code with a debugger?

Comment: how could i fix my code

Comment: By debugging your code and inspecting variables and discovering what is going wrong.

Comment: i have not learned how to use debugger

Comment: This may get you started: [How do you debug a C program on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176795/how-do-you-debug-a-c-program-on-windows)

Comment: im really trying to debug but its not working on my pc!!!